# Does std::static_pointer_cast have any additional runtime overhead?

Tags: c++

Compared to static_cast, that is. So, if we have these two casts

```
Base* b(new Derived());
Derived* d = static_cast<Derived*>(b); // (1)

shared_ptr<Base> b(new Derived());
shared_ptr<Derived> d = static_pointer_cast<Derived>(b); // (2)
```

will line (2) be slower than line (1)?

Comment: It's just syntactic sugar for `static_cast<Derived*>(b.get())`.

Comment: @Rapptz: `static_pointer_cast` work on `shared_ptr` smart pointer objects.

Comment: @Rapptz This can't be quite true, since the pointer returned by static_pointer_cast shares ownership with the original pointer.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but n3797 says `The seemingly equivalent expression shared_ptr<T>(static_cast<T*>(r.get())) will eventually result in undeﬁned behavior, attempting to delete the same object twice.`

Comment: @remyabel, You are correct, that's why the two expressions are only *seemingly* equivalent.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, it has more overhead, because it has to return a new shared_ptr as opposed to a new raw pointer.

The boost implementation is:

```
template<class T, class U> shared_ptr<T> static_pointer_cast( shared_ptr<U> const & r ) BOOST_NOEXCEPT
{
    (void) static_cast< T* >( static_cast< U* >( 0 ) );

    typedef typename shared_ptr<T>::element_type E;

    E * p = static_cast< E* >( r.get() );
    return shared_ptr<T>( r, p );
}
```

So the return line creates a shared_ptr which owns the very same raw pointer as the shared_ptr you are casting. Looking at this constructor, it will cause an assignment of both the pointer being managed and a pointer to the control block - this is the extra overhead. It's basically two pointer assignments instead of one.

Edit 2: There will also be an atomic reference count increment, the performance impact of which will be more than a normal increment.

Edit: Usual caveats where performance issues apply. Implementations can vary. This is not a standard-mandated overhead. And always always measure performance!

Comment: You forgot the cost of incrementing the reference count (atomic operations are a lot more expensive than normal) because the cast effectively copies the shared_ptr. I know the spec doesn't mention reference counters but virtually all implementations do use them and they have to be atomic (thread safe).

Comment: @John5342 I thought this initially, changed my mind and edited it out of my answer, but now I am back to agreeing with you :) When I changed my mind, I had misread the spec.

Comment: Would you please kindly tell what's the purpose of `(void) static_cast< T* >( static_cast< U* >( 0 ) );` for boost implementation(i guess it's something about the type check, but not sure the exact details)?

Answer (score 1):

A `shared_ptr` keeps the info it needs for referred object destruction in the common control block, along with a deleter functor. The common control block is shared among `shared_ptr` instances for the same referred object. A `static_pointer_cast` merely casts the pointer in a `shared_ptr` instance, and so, even though *it can change the pointer value*, it should not involve any extra overhead (except `shared_ptr` instance creation, as with copying one).

AFAIK there is, however, no formal guarantee (but check it if it's important to you).